# tympanus codrops page layout inspired by flipboard

Tags: jquery, html, flipboard

When i am using the page layout inspired by flipboard from tympanus i am not able to select stuff inside the selected content.

For example: If i am in a specific page and i click in one box, the content in that box appears inside a div that occupies full screen, but i am not able to select any of its content.
 In particular if i try to select an image with mouse left button to open it in a new window i can't.

This is the link to the project:
http://tympanus.net/Development/FlipboardPageLayout/